# PHP: Convert Scientific E value to Number

Tags: php

I need to convert following scientific e values to plain string or real number in php

```
$num1 = 1.2378147769392E+14;

$num2 = 4.9999999999998E-6;

echo number_format($num1, 0, '', ''); // o/p:- 123781477693920

echo number_format($num2, 0, '', ''); // o/p:- 0
```

The expected output for $num2 is **0.0000049999999999998**

[image]

The output should come as shown above.

Ref Link: http://www.easysurf.cc/scintd.htm

TIA

Comment: What have you tried? Where did it go wrong?

Comment: I tried 
number_format(1.2378147769392E+14,0,'','') which is giving me proper output 123781477693920

But when I am using it with number_format(4.9999999999998E-6, 0, '', '')
It is showing 0 the expected output is 0.0000049999999999998

Comment: You cannot use a standard PHP function for this, like `sprintf()`. The reason is that PHP will convert the number to a floating number and you loose some information in the process. You have to treat the scientific numbers as strings and process them that way.

Comment: Thanks KIKO Software

Answer (score 0):

```
$num1 = (int)1.2378147769392E+14;
```

echo $num1 will return the real number a 123781477693920

```
$num2 = (int)4.9999999999998E-6;
```

echo $num2 also will return the real number as 0